# SQLite FTS3 installation, unable to create virtual table after installation

Tags: macos, sqlite, fts3

I a bit new to sqllite lite and linux commands so any help would be greatly appreciated!  Is there something I am missing?

After the sqlite-3.7.3 installation, for some reason I am still still not seeing the new version **(sqlite-3.7.3)** when checking with

macbook-pro:sqlite-3.7.3 scott$ *which sqlite3*

/usr/bin/sqlite3

macbook-pro:sqlite-3.7.3 scott$ sqlite3 test.db

SQLite version **3.6.12**
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"

sqlite> create virtual table vt using fts3();

**SQL error: no such module: fts3**

sqlite installation dump:

macbook-pro:sqlite-3.7.3 scott$ sudo make install
test -z "/usr/local/lib" || /Users/scott/sqlite-3.7.3/install-sh -d "/usr/local/lib"
 /bin/sh ./libtool --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c  'libsqlite3.la' '/usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.la'
/usr/bin/install -c .libs/libsqlite3.0.8.6.dylib /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.0.8.6.dylib
(cd /usr/local/lib && { ln -s -f libsqlite3.0.8.6.dylib libsqlite3.0.dylib || { rm -f libsqlite3.0.dylib && ln -s libsqlite3.0.8.6.dylib libsqlite3.0.dylib; }; })
(cd /usr/local/lib && { ln -s -f libsqlite3.0.8.6.dylib libsqlite3.dylib || { rm -f libsqlite3.dylib && ln -s libsqlite3.0.8.6.dylib libsqlite3.dylib; }; })
/usr/bin/install -c .libs/libsqlite3.lai /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.la
/usr/bin/install -c .libs/libsqlite3.a /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.a
chmod 644 /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.a

### ranlib /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.a

Libraries have been installed in:
   /usr/local/lib

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the`DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for

### more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.

test -z "/usr/local/bin" || /Users/scott/sqlite-3.7.3/install-sh -d "/usr/local/bin"
  /bin/sh ./libtool --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c 'sqlite3' '/usr/local/bin/sqlite3'
/usr/bin/install -c .libs/sqlite3 /usr/local/bin/sqlite3
test -z "/usr/local/include" || /Users/scott/sqlite-3.7.3/install-sh -d "/usr/local/include"
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 'sqlite3.h' '/usr/local/include/sqlite3.h'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 'sqlite3ext.h' '/usr/local/include/sqlite3ext.h'
test -z "/usr/local/share/man/man1" || /Users/scott/sqlite-3.7.3/install-sh -d "/usr/local/share/man/man1"
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 './sqlite3.1' '/usr/local/share/man/man1/sqlite3.1'
test -z "/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig" || /Users/scott/sqlite-3.7.3/install-sh -d "/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig"
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 'sqlite3.pc' '/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/sqlite3.pc'scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you install the `sqlite3` command and what is your path? Type

```
echo $PATH
```

and check whether the dir where the command is located precedes `/usr/bin`, where SQLite 3.6 is installed. If it doesn't, change your path in `.bashrc`.

Comment: Thanks for responding, Larsmans!  
scott$ echo $PATH

/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin

Comment: If you installed to `/usr/local/bin`, do `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin` in a terminal. The path is searched left-to-right. Also change `.bashrc` so the path is set to the new value at login.

Comment: I executed this line: 
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin

Sorry, I am a noob at this...  How do i change the .bashrc file so that the path is set to the new value at login?

Comment: Does SQLite 3.7 work now? In that case, open the file `.bashrc` in your homedir using any text editor (note: it's a hidden file), look for a line that sets the `PATH` variable and change that.

Comment: Yeah, is working now!  You are awesome man!  Do I still need to make change to .bashrc file?

Comment: Yes, because when you exit the terminal, the environment is forgotten. Change `.bashrc`, fire up a new terminal, and see if the `PATH` is still changed. If it isn't (at least some versions of OS X apparently ignore `.bashrc`), change `.bash_profile` instead.